# How can I loop through a number of variables in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Basically, I have the following clunky set of `if` statements in my code put in place to set any erroneous sensor readings to zero.

```cpp
if (soil_moisture > 150 || soil_moisture <-100){
    soil_moisture = 0;
}
if (soil_temperature > 150 || soil_temperature < -100 ){
    soil_temperature = 0;
}
if (ambient_temperature > 150 || ambient_temperature < -100 ){
    ambient_temperature = 0;
}
if (ambient_humidity > 150 || ambient_humidity <-100){
    ambient_humidity = 0;
}
```

The way it's written seems redundant and inefficient, and I'm wondering, if there's a better way of doing this. Is it possible to create an array of the variables `soil_temperature`, `soil_moisture`, etc... and then loop through these variables in a `for` loop, which has the `if` statement embedded in it?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to do this although a loop would work too. Depending on your idea of "efficient". Is smaller code more efficient? Less writing or less instructions. For the first criteria, a loop would be far more efficient. For the second, this holds true also. Instruction per instruction though, this is a very efficient method.

Comment: Why would you put values to 0, if 0 is a valid in-bounds value? I foresee some potentially horrible bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to do this although a loop would work too. Depending on your idea of "efficient". Is smaller code more efficient? Less writing or less instructions. For the first criteria, a loop would be far more efficient. For the second, this holds true also. Instruction per instruction though, this is a very efficient method.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

So for me, I think the efficiency would come from adding more sensors; so if I add a 5th sensor, say, I'd rather not have to write a fifth if statement. It would be great if I can just append it to an array. This array would then be put through that -100 / 150 for loop to clean any erroneous values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper routine to trim down the code:

```
boolean outOfBounds(int value, int low, int high)
{
    if ( value < low || value > high ) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then in your code ...

```
if ( outOfBounds(soil_moisture, -100, 150) ) {
    soil_moisture = 0;
}
if ( outOfBounds(soil_temperature, -100, 150) ) {
    soil_temperature = 0;
}
// etc.
```

If your limits are always -100 and 150, then you could pass a pointer to the variable, and set it to zero within the routine:

```
void resetBounds(int *pvar)
{
    if ( *pvar < -100 || *pvar > 150 ) {
        *pvar = 0;
    }
}
```

In your code:

```
resetBounds(&soil_moisture);
resetBounds(&soil_temperature);
// etc.
```

Pretty clean to my eyes.

As for your loop, yes, that would work, but it implies the overhead of copying the values into an array, and then looping over them, which distracts from what you're doing to them. It's almost like the mechaism gets in way of seeing what's happening. Just my opinion.

Have fun!